# Mysql Load File Error loading inaccurate data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hi I have a csv dataset like

ukwn,34,2018-10-01,"757,271"

ukwn,3,2018-10-01,"7,342"

"hi",23,2018-10-01,"3,483,887"

i want to insert it in the database so i made the code:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE app_spend_metric 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1,col2,col3,col4)

But i fails to insert the col4 (4th row) as there is ',' inside a "" like "7,345"

I tried then,

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE app_spend_metric 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1,col2,col3,col4)

But this time it enters the partial data in col4 like out of "7,344" it only enters "7

Answer (score 0):

If col4 is numeric (eg, `INT`), then the problem is as follows:

1. Parse the line to get the string `"7,344"`
2. Strip the enclosing `"`:  `7,344`
3. Store the string into the `INT` column.  This requires converting that string to a number.
4. Conversion stops at the first non-numeric character, namely the comma.
5. Result:  The `col4` is set to 7, and `,344` is tossed.

MySQL cannot deal with "thousands-separators" in numbers.  But you could strip them:

```
LOAD ...
    (col1, col2, col3, @num)
    SET col4 = REPLACE(@num, ',', '')
```

Comment: Hi, there are 4 colums

Comment: @user9092050 - I rewrote my answer to explain how to parse the commas.